# Libreoffice does not open

Tags: libreoffice

I recently tried to update libreoffice on my pc I use ubuntu 18.04, but i think the update was not taken well. I decided to fully uninstall the libreoffice package and reinstalled it (version 7.1.1) again. However the problem i have been having now is that when i try open libreoffice (writer, impress, calc) it tries to open but then stops. After waiting for a long time, nothing happens. I can't even open a file.

I tried to delete the libreoffice folder in .config folder as advised by some people on the site but it did not help.

I have tried several times to uninstall and reinstall Libreoffice as well as rebooting the pc but this has not solved the problem.

Could anyone have an idea how i can solve this?

Comment: please read [ask] and [edit] your question with further details in particular, the version of Ubuntu and the version of LO. When you start LO do you see it listed on the left of the top bar (system tray) next to `Activities`?

Comment: Version of ubuntu is ubuntu 18.04 bionic. The version of LO is 7.11.  I tried it with other lower versions of LO but still i experienced the same problem. And yes when i start libreoffice, it is listed on the left top bar with but then disappears after a few seconds and nothing happens after even after waiting for minutes and hours

Answer (score 0):

You've given insufficient information to diagnose the problem. However, you could try an alternative route.

1. Completely uninstall Libre Office.
2. Open a terminal and run

`snap install libreoffice`

Then try again.

Ubuntu includes the facility to use snaps, which are self-contained and therefore more resistant to this type of problem.

On an older machine, a snap takes a little longer to open (several seconds in my experience), but runs fine once it has started.

Comment: In the case of LibreOffice, "Completely uninstall Libre Office" is not trivial: Libreoffice is a suite of packages, _none of which is called_ `libreoffice`. Therefore it would be helpful to show which specific command is capable of the operation.

Comment: This has solved my problem. Now my life is back to normal. Thank you so much

Comment: Good to hear, @NaahJoeh. Please mark the answer as a solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @Levente — Indeed yes. I had thought about adding `sudo apt autoremove`, but then I worried that it might cause unrelated problems. As the OP already knew how to uninstall LibreOffice, I figured that it would be safer to leave it to the OP's discretion.